# numpy array permutation changes order of axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to permute an array using a fixed order determined in another array. However, when i try to do so, the shape of the array changes. Is this expected behaviour? If so, why is this expected?

For example

```
a = np.random.normal(size=(12,5,2,2,3))
shuffle_order = np.random.permutation(np.arange(5))
b = a[:,shuffle_order,:,0]
```

I would expect b.shape = (12,5,2,3). However in reality b.shape is (5, 12, 2, 3)

I am using numpy 1.19.5

Comment: You're actually getting 5 (size of shuffle_order) samples out of `a[:, x, :, 0]` (x being one element in shuffle_order). So NumPy is stacking 5 arrays of shape `(12, 2, 3)` (first, third and fourth dimension) into `(5, 12, 2, 3)`.

Comment: ok great thanks! I'm assuming b.swapaxes(0,1) will return what I'm looking for?

Comment: I think swapaxes (or like functions) can probably work in your case. I don't actually see an option to permute along a single axis for a *given*  permutation (for a random permutation along one axis, there are existing NumPy functions).

Comment: Looks like you are not grabbing enough of the axes..

Comment: Looks like a case of mixing advanced and basic indexing.  This is documented.  The sliced dimensions get put at the end.  Try `b=a[:,shuffle_order][...,0]`